# SAX Parser : parsing XML having "\&gt" and "\&lt" inside the XML element

Tags: java, xml, parsing, saxparser

While parsing an XML file which contain &gt and &lt data.

Data in XML:
`<details>Name=\&lt;myName\&gt;,Group=1,Domain=\&lt;DomainId\&gt;..\&lt;oPC\&gt;,Address=\&lt;myAddress\&gt;</details>`

Response after parsing : 
`<details>Name=\<myName\>,Group=1,Domain=\<DomainId\>..\<oPC\>,Address=\<myAddress\></details>`

We are replaced all `&lt` by "<" and `&gt` by ">" as this is standard way of parsing XML.

But, this data is invalid as it contains '\' and we get exception `Element type "myName" must be followed by either attribute specifications, ">" or "/>"`.

Do we need to manually replace "\" while parsing data ?

Comment: Tried checking class org.xml.sax.ext.LexicalHandler ?

Comment: Replacing all &lt by "<" and &gt by ">" - before feeding the result to the parser - is not the "standard way of parsing XML", please show your actual Java code.

Comment: As you have not showed any code. Maybe having a look at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/sax/parsing.html could point you already in the right direction.

Comment: `\\` is just an ordinary character in an XML file.